# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 8007007f

Tags: vb.net, com, clsid

I have a message error when I run my software application and that I open a window that is using EXCEL in the background.

This is the detail message error that I get :

************** Exception Text **************

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007007F): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
error: 8007007f La procédure spécifiée est introuvable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F).
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.AllocateUninitializedObject(RuntimeType
objectType)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
serverType)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(RuntimeType
serverType, Object[] props, Boolean bNewObj)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at WindowsApplication1.Aux_Publiques.Detection_Fichier_OTIF_Fournisseurs()
   at WindowsApplication1.frm_OTIF.frm_OTIF_Disposed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at WindowsApplication1.frm_OTIF.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmClose(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

'----------------------------------------------

I have tried this solution already :

[Here](https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.TECH170889)

Anybody has an idea ?

I will remain at your disposal to answer questions

Thanks you.

Comment: That's a pretty gross error.  Not terribly unusual for an in-process COM server, corrupted DLL problem, but Excel is an out-of-process server.  You'd at minimum consider re-installing Excel but the damage is probably more severe and an OS dll like ole32.dll is corrupted.  Also a good reason to be concerned about malware, Office is a very attractive target.  Use another machine.